# return a list or array that contains values based on dictionary keys without using for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary `{'A':1,'B':2,'C':3}`

i want to map a list `['A','B','A','A','B]` to dictionary values **without using for loop or unnecessary if statements** the output should be `[1,2,1,1,2]` in array or list from.

I tried to do this using `np.vectorize` and `map` but it is a `for` loop. I need to do this without using any loops or unnecessary if statements to get the required result mentioned above.

Comment: Why on earth would you not want to use the best solution. A loop.

Comment: does list comprehension count as a for loop?

Comment: A list comprehension is a for loop and essentially just saves  coding space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done using list or map with dictionary 'get'

```
d = {'A':1,'B':2,'C':3}
l = ['A','B','A','A','B']
result = list(map(d.get, l))
```

Comment: Short, consise solution with just built-in functions. Nicely done.

Comment: [map](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3af4b585527743e455145d294049c46b7c823ed9/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1194) uses a for loop, so that's not a solution.

Comment: Your solution, @kincaid, seems to be the fastest one, by far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itemgetter`

```
from operator import itemgetter

d = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
lst = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B']
lst = itemgetter(*lst)(d)
print(lst) # (1, 2, 1, 1, 2)
```

Comment: This is a slightly faster solution but i want something that is faster if possible.

Comment: That's still a for loop because [`itemgetter`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/operator.py) uses [`map`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3af4b585527743e455145d294049c46b7c823ed9/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1194) which uses a for loop, so that's not a solution.

Comment: @SyedMuhammadZain how fast? do you have a specific requirement?

Comment: @harryhaller to go over all the keys-values of a `dict` you need to iterate over it, explicitly or not. Some implementation provides better performance but you still need to do the iteration.

Comment: I have already implemented a solution using numpy that uses no for loops or if statements but i want something that is better.

Comment: I had to use np.vectorize to implement it but i found out that it is a for loop so i need better solutions now.

Comment: @SyedMuhammadZain you need to iterate over the `list` one way or another.

Comment: I need as fast as possible hopefully using numpy or something im searching for a solution all over but i couldnt find it.

Comment: The data structure can be changed to something else.

Comment: if i need to iterate this one way or another which is the fastest iteration option avaliable

Comment: @SyedMuhammadZain If you want the fastest solution, the answer is in plain sight: *don't use python*.

Comment: @Guy: Any suggested answer that uses a for loop, implicitly or explicitly, does not satisfy the requirements of the original poster and hence does not qualify as a solution (he did not ask for the solution with best performance). I agree, though, that there is no other way than using a loop, hence there should be no answers to this question.

Comment: If you want to get super duper speed, check the C programming language. And if you are using Unix/Linux you can even pipe from languages such as python, into a C program.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without for loops or if statements, *as per your specification*.

```
d = {'A':1,'B':2,'C':3}
l = ['A','B','A','A','B','z']

def replace_in_list(mapping, list_iterator):
    try:
        val = mapping[next(list_iterator)]
    except KeyError:
        val = None
    except StopIteration:
        return []
    return [val] + replace_in_list(mapping, list_iterator)

result = replace_in_list(d, iter(l))
print(result)  # [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `numpy`:

```
(np.sum((np.array(l) == np.array(list(d.keys()))[:,None]) *
        np.array(list(d.values()))[:,None], axis=0))
```

Output:

```
array([1, 2, 1, 1, 2])
```